# Email Logo Doesn't work

Tags: email, logo, magento2.2.3

We are working on **Magento ver 2.2.3** and inserted a logo into transactional emails, but it never work.

We have the same error over and over, we tried to look on the vendor theme path, (there is not header.html, could be that the error?

[image]

Comment: If you go to Admin > Content > Design > Configuration > Edit any record -> Transactional Emails is the logo broken there too?

Comment: Nop, there the logo appears right. Is just on the email

Answer (score -1):

I guess the easiest way, without playing with any code is to manually add the logo image:

1) create the directory `pub/media/email/logo/default`

2) copy the logo to the directory manually using FTP.

3) Then via the correct procedure 
**Content > Design > Configuration > Edit > Transnational emails >**

Once finished, upload the same logo you manually added to the newly created directory.

Comment: Great! Mark this answer as accepted to keep the community clean :)

Comment: After put an html code with the logo. Still happend the same. If I press preview in the template manager the logo is there, but when I send the email, the email never appear. Could be a problem with my server or a problem with my magento?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9590 this might help you solving the problem. I believe this is Magento rather than server.

Comment: I saw it before text here. I have running Magento 2.2.3, and I posted on GitHub too, but no one answer yet.

Comment: Any luck with it?

Comment: No, also I put the code in the email template just to see what happens, and still happening the same, no image appears.

Comment: What code did you use in the email?

Comment: <img src="https://store.holidaygym.es/img/logo.png" alt="Holiday Gym" height="356" width="102">

Comment: Hymm I can see this img... It might be working just fine. See... To help protect your privacy, some content of emails may be blocked. This usually involves images too. What client are you using for emails?

Comment: I´m using magento to send them and to get them I´m trying in gmail.

Comment: In gmail, open the emial you have received from your store and click on "more" in the right hand corener. Then click on "Show original" and try to find the part of the email in regards to the logo to look for anything unusual

Comment: I did it, but still